# Add a Low Quality Posts button to delete answer because it doesn't answer the question

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I think there should be an option when you select "Recommend Deletion" for "Does not answer the question being asked".

I'm seeing quite a large number of answers that really do not actually answer the question and there really is no option to indicate this to the person who wrote it. For those answers, I end up selecting "No comment needed". It would be nice to indicate the actual problem.

Did I happen to receive a disproportionate amount of those answers or do they really constitute a significant portion of the Low Quality Posts?

Incidentally, there are also a number of answers that are just plain wrong or doesn't actually work (While, they at least are an attempt to answer the actual question), but there is no option for that either.

Comment: I think your request is a good one, but I'd change the wording to something like "Does not answer the question being asked"

Comment: There are already all necessary available, to realize such. Just downvote/flag the answer, and move on.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In that particular queue, you actually don't have the option to downvote or flag the answer

Comment: How big of a problem is this? Why isn't downvoting sufficient? Can you offer examples?

Comment: @Shog9 I'm happy to click "Looks OK" as per the accepted answer. As I stated in some of the other comments, there is no downvote button in the review screen, and also, if you follow the link to the actual answer and downvote there, the post will presumably still be in the queue. So my question really relates to what the appropriate action is to get it out of the review queue

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are asking for is more than a cosmetic change to the user interface but a **change in policy**.

I **hate** answers that don't actually answer the question as much as you do, but...

#### The Current Policy

As it stands right now, we are not supposed to flag as NAA or VLQ those answers which *look* like answers but *actually* do not answer the question. So you should never have to click "Recommend Deletion" in the review queue because the answer is not actually answering the question. **If you see such answers in the queue that's because someone flagged them in spite of the policy in place.**

There is a good reason we don't open the NAA flag to such answers. With the policy currently in place, most of the time an answer that has been pushed into the LQ queue **can be evaluated without knowing anything about the technology involved.** An answer that says:

> Thanks for the solution...

or

> Can someone help me...

is worthy of deletion. It does not matter whether the post continues with C# code, JavaScript, SQL, or whatever. They can also be evaluated **without having to look at the question.** Exceptions exist but they are relatively rare.

#### Allowing Answers that don't Actually Answer the Question to be NAA

If you open NAA to include such answers then **you'll always have to read the question to decide whether these answers should be deleted** and a substantial number of such answers **will require knowledge of the specific technologies involved** in order to decide whether they should be deleted.

Suppose someone asks "What does the `++` operator do in JavaScript?" and someone answers "You can't assign to `None` in Python." It is blindingly obvious the answer is not answering the question. However, there are a great deal of cases where the answer is not answering the question but this fact is *not obvious* unless you have really good knowledge about the technology involved. I see this happen repeatedly in the [requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requirejs) tag: newbies in the technology post answers that in some *other cases* could actually have something to do with the problem but *not here*. These are not actually answering the question but only someone whose substantially worked with RequireJS would know this. And I know by the downvotes such answers are *not getting* (except from me) that very few people manage to realize that the answer is not actually answering the question.

Among the answers that don't actually answer the question, the fact of the matter is that I see many more answers of the non-obvious kind than answers of the obvious kind. If such answers would be allowed to be marked as NAA, people would soon filter the LQ queue by technology and we'd see the queue grow and grow and grow, like the close queue.

#### When the Obvious is Wrong

Moreover, what *appears* obvious is not always necessarily so. My favorite examples are: Selenium questions and questions marked with [coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coffeescript). So Alice comes across a Selenium question that is written in Java and sees that Bob wrote an answer in Python. This is an *obvious* case where the answer is not answering the question, right? Not so fast! It is common in the community of Selenium users to accept answers that are written in a language different from the one they use because the Selenium API is regular from language to language. If you know Java, it is fairly easy to translate the Python answer to working Java code. Then Alice sees a question in CoffeeScript and sees that Bob (damn Bob!) posted an answer in JavaScript. Obviously it is not answering the question! Again, not so fast! The CoffeeScript community regularly accepts answers written in JavaScript.

#### The Upshot

If you want to follow the policy as it is, then when you encounter an answer that looks like an answer in the LQ queue, and there's no other reason to delete it, then you hit "Looks Ok".

If you really don't like the answer and can't bring yourself to click "Looks OK", click "Skip".

Comment: Do you suggest that I select "Looks OK"?

Comment: If you want to follow the current policy then "Looks OK" is what you should select, assuming there's no other problem with the post. If it is too unpalatable for you to select "Looks OK" for a post you despise, you can hit "Skip".

Comment: I'm happy to follow whatever policy the community has decided. I will select "Looks OK" from now on. Just wanted to clarify the action you suggested as it was not perfectly clear to me from your answer

Comment: True. I've added a final section to rectify that.

Comment: Excellent answer, particularly the examples of cases where evaluating these is not at all clear-cut.

Comment: ++ all fkn day long i've been trying to say that.. naugh, just got tons of downvotes...

Comment: @vba4all The upvotes and downvotes are unrelated to the answer; it's just because Louis is way cooler than you.

Answer (score 3):

When i come across those, i use the *comment on another post* reason, but i agree that it would be useful to have a dedicated item for this.

Answer (score -2):

It would mean that when you select *`Does not answer the question being asked`* as the reason for deletion a comment will be added below the answer.

Well, if something *`doesn't answer the question being asked`* what do we do? We **downvote**... 3 downvotes and the answer is gone.

Comment: Please specify what you disagree with, because it sounds like you may confusing the page I refer to with other places on the site, but you may just disagree with my wording for the option. On this specific review page, there is no "Not An Answer" option when you review (That option is available if you Flag an answer). You also don't have the option to Flag instead of Recommend Deletion. Additionally, you cannot Downvote on that page either. You can follow a link to the original post. If do that and Downvote / Flag, what should you do in the review... Skip or Looks OK or Recommend Deletion?

Comment: So what if the question asks "how do I split a string by slashes" and an answer instead says "you shouldn't use classes as they do not follow OOP principles"?

Comment: That's NAA, that does not go to a low quality.

Comment: the [answer you refer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122443/what-does-the-very-low-quality-flag-mean-in-regards-to-answers) seems to explain how to use flags, not how to make decisions when reviewing in the queue

Comment: @gnat but you should be well aware why flags are cast... isn't that the reason there are different queues for different types of problems with posts?

Comment: I don't play guessing games about what was on flagger's mind or what heuristics triggered the script to automagically push the post into review queue

Answer (score -2):

> I think there should be an option when you select "Recommend Deletion" for "Does not answer **the** question being asked"

The problem with NAA is that through it says "but it does not attempt to answer **the** question" most people interpret it as "but it does not attempt to answer **any** question at all". This is evident when you see NAA's flags declined because someone wrote an answer to the wrong question (ie. how to do X in java and the answer propose *without a good reason* how to do Y in python). I propose instead merging both NAA's and VLQ's flags into a single flag and then breaking down the selection, as how the off topic flags are, into:

- Delete this post because...

  - is a comment to another post
  - is an edit to another post
  - doesn't answer this question as it's currently posed, it may be an answer to another question. (only answers)
  - has severe formatting or content problems. This post is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.
  - is no more than a link to another resource. There's nothing in the answer itself to even hint at what direction we're being pointed in.
  - is another question posted as answer. (only answers)
  - is a "thank you" comment.
  - is a "I'm having this problem too". (only answers)

I know the break down sucks. I just scrapped more or less the comments of the LQRQ, but I think is an step forward towards a good direction.

Comment: Why not do this break down in the VLQ -> delete dialog where it already is?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not following.

Comment: You are suggesting to put an extra dialog inside the initial flagging dialog, aren't you? I think it should go to the reviewers' "delete because" dialog

Comment: @JanDvorak ah, yeah. Sort of what is happening with the current OT reasons. Instead of "spam, offensive, naa, vlq, other" it would be "spam, offensive, delete, other".

Comment: I'm not a fan of that. Reviewers should be able to tell why an answer is bad without a hint like that. I can't see any benefit of such a hint.

Comment: @JanDvorak my proposal doesn't affect the VLQ review queue, only the flaggers and moderators UI.

Comment: Now that's the point. Flaggers don't need this kind of help. Reviewers do. Or rather, reviewers are looking for better ways to express their reasons to delete.

Comment: @JanDvorak no. Right now, to convert an answer to a comment I have to flag "other" otherwise the moderators (the ultimate reviewers) has to guess my intentions. Both VLQ and NAA's flags only says "myeah, there's somethin' wrong here, figure out what is". If you instead break down flags into *specific situations*, self-documented of what's the usage for each flag is, you are taking a leap forward to improve the system. Flaggers can't interpret the flag for what "it shouldn't be used for", and moderators (reviewers) know exactly what was the intent of the flagger.

Comment: Tempting, but... Every time you "enumerate badness" you hit the same problem: more overhead up front, plus you give folks a "bingo card" that they try to fill by comparing every post they see against it. Given that folks are already applying ridiculously broad interpretations for problems like "link only answer", I don't see this ending well.