# NAA Flag Declined (I know)

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I'm sure this is all your favorite kind of question but I'm just looking for some feedback. Usually my NAA flags are successful and it's my most common type of flag.

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32482034/2588818) to a pretty bad question that seems 100% to me like it should have been a clarifying comment, but the user doesn't have enough rep to do so. That's usually why I flag, so I did, NAA without comment. I see now that it even has an auto-comment from a review queue (I'm guessing) expressing the same sentiment.

I got back:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I don't understand this at all. I don't find there to be anything technically inaccurate or wrong here. I also don't see any code or anything that provides an answer to the question, such as it is.

## Edit:

The text of the "Not an Answer" flag is as follows, with my emphasis:

> This was posted as an answer, but **it does not attempt to answer the question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

These are the exact specifications from the OP's question:

- read the text file line by line from Top to Bottom
- takes the last Char from each line, even if there is only 1 Char at that line, and places him in the Next line, just before the last Char. (because when it jumps to the Next line, and moves this lines last char, the last Char from the previous line will be this lines new last char)
- and finally write that all to a new text file

The "answer" simply warns to *also* check for blank lines when you do this. It does not provide code, and it does not in any way attempt to answer any of the specifications.

## Edit 2:

In response to several comments below and some obvious confusion between what is the actual policy as applied in practice and what is written in the UI and help files, I ask this:

Can anyone provide a clear and consistent definintion of 'answer', which explains what is and is not an answer, without something ethereal that echoes [Potter Stewart's Definition of 'Pornography'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)?

Comment: Looks like an attempted answer to me.  If you think it's a bad answer, downvote it.  I fail to see how it's not an answer.

Comment: @Servy Are you kidding? The question is about how to read through a text file, reorder it based on certain symbols, then rewrite the sorted version to a new file. This answer says nothing more than, "Ooh, and if you have blank lines, don't forget about those too!" without answering any of the other parts.

Comment: That would make it an incorrect answer, not "not an answer".  The fact that an answer *fails* to answer the question doesn't make it NAA.

Comment: "_it should have been a clarifying comment_" probably.  But it could _also_ be a very vague answer.  It's so borderline of a case that I'm only mildly surprised that your flag was declined.  I personally wouldn't have flagged it outside a review queue.

Comment: @Servy Then what exactly is the difference between an answer and a clarifying comment? If you ignore the question entirely and simply point out a potential problem, that should be a comment. It seems like you're saying that if someone asked, "How do I hook up a printer?" and I said, "It depends if you're using Windows or Mac," that would be a valid "answer."

Comment: I would like to point out again: this "answer" is not necessarily incorrect. It also does not in any way attempt to answer the question as written. Do "answers" to different questions entirely count, then? If someone asks, "Who was the first president of the United States?" and I answer, "The square root of 16 is 4," that wouldn't qualify?

Comment: Related feature-req: [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen According to what I'm seeing, you should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What you're misunderstanding is how mods process that flag: By looking at the answer and judging if it looks like an attempt to answer. They don't take it in the context of the question- So long as it _looks_ like an attempt to answer, they decline the flag. Out of the context of the question, it _looks_ like an (albeit poor) answer. That's the general rule of thumb for the NAA flag. If it looks like it could be an answer, even if it misses the mark entirely, NAA is _not_ the right way to go.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist To your last example, no, that's *not* "not an answer".  You could say it's a Very Low Quality answer, probably even of sufficiently low quality to delete, but it's not Not An Answer per the definition of NAA.  NAA is for non-answers, not bad/wrong/failed answers.

Comment: @Servy And what about my first example? I'm just looking for clear, consistent guidance on what counts as an answer and what doesn't. I'm more confused than when I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Your first example is a clarifying question.  That Not An Answer.  It's not even *attempting* to be an answer.  It would qualify for a flag.

Comment: I just want to know what question goes with that 'answer'.

Comment: @Servy And that is exactly the reasoning I used on my declined flag above. Perhaps now you see the problem. After all, "It depends if you use Mac or Windows" _could_ be answering the question, "Does X work consistently no matter what platform I'm on?" It's not a very _good_ or particularly spelled out answer to that question, but it's an answer!

Comment: @Servy I feel like you and others are so confident in the way you approach this and that my approach was wrong, but that you can't explain it in a clear way that (a.) doesn't reference "implementation details" in the way the StackOverflow UI is put together depending on your rep, or (b.) doesn't contradict itself on what counts as an "answer" or what reasoning should be used in cases like this. And I think that is a problem. There's a reason these questions are on Meta every day...

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist No, asking a clarifying question is *not* posting an answer, even if the answer to the clarifying question might lead one to figure out what the actual answer is.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes, it's quite simple.  You flag a post as NAA if it is not an attempt to answer the question.  It is wrong to cast such a flag on any attempted answer, even if that answer is a *failed* attempt to answer the question, or a low quality attempt to answer the question.  Asking a clarifying question isn't even an *attempt* at an answer.  Posting something that the author thinks is an answer but that is just wrong, or that misunderstands the question, is still an attempted answer.  If you think an answer is *bad*, downvote, don't flag.

Comment: @Servy You're just talking past me. I do not see the above as a failed attempt to answer the question. I see it as a clarifying question in statement form. You have not shown me why it is different from other things you agree are mere clarifications. You have not demonstrated in what way it attempts to answer the question. The actual answer here would have been a method of sorting the file according to the specification. The "answer" does not even mention this. It mentions a potential problem with what would be an answer, if there were one. Equivalent: "Are there blank lines in your files?"

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist How is it a clarifying question?  It's not expecting information from the OP.  It's explaining what he thinks is wrong and how to fix it.  You think what he is describing, whether true or not, wouldn't solve that problem.  That makes it a failed answer, not, "not an answer".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When moderators go through NAA flags, [they only see the answer, but not the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224449/sanity-check-on-naa-flag/224452#224452).  Therefore, most moderators will tend to decline NAA flags on things that look like they *might* be valid answers.

In fact, according to current policy, [NAA flags should not be used for things that look like answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276162/add-a-low-quality-posts-button-to-delete-answer-because-it-doesnt-answer-the-qu/276197#276197), even if they don't actually answer the specific question asked.  Sometimes such answers do get flagged, and sometimes they even get deleted, either by normal users in the LQP review queue or by [moderators that go the extra mile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286043/why-was-my-not-an-answer-flag-declined-as-having-no-evidence#comment155113_286045) and actually look at the question page in ambiguous cases.  But officially, we're not supposed to use NAA flags in such cases.

Unfortunately, the text in the flag description that you quoted does kind of contradict this policy, which tends to cause some confusion here.  I've previously [suggested changing the NAA flag description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag) to more closely match the actual way NAA flags are currently supposed to be used, but so far nothing has come out of that.

Comment: This is the real answer. I get that mods don't have a lot of context here, but this policy is not clearly spelled out anywhere except this meta question I hadn't come across, and as you say the text of NAA would not help me understand it. Also, if the problem is that mods don't have a lot of context, it seems like that is a UI problem.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist No, it's not a UI problem.  The question isn't showed because *the question doesn't matter*.  Whether a given post correctly answers the question asked has no determination as to whether it's An Answer or not.  It's relevant to determining if it's a *correct* answer, but that's not what NAA are there to judge.  A post that is Not An Answer is clearly not an answer even when judged in isolation, without seeing the question.

Answer (score 9):

When I see a non-answer that **in the absence of a question might appear to be an answer** I add a comment before flagging. For example I might say

> This isn't an answer to the question, which asked what temperature to roast chicken at. These ideas for what to do with leftover roast chicken are an answer to an entirely different question

I haven't had any NAA flags declined when I've left a comment like that. On a high volume site like SO, you might want to use a custom flag instead of NAA and include the same comment text in the flag, just to save the moderator a step and ensure your full context is there for them. (I'd still leave the comment for the user, who needs to learn.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try this in the future.

Comment: You make me feel hungry now...

Comment: I think this is excellent advice -- whenever it's even slightly non-trivial to evaluate a flag from the text of the answer I leave a comment.

Comment: I should note that we also don't see comments by default in the flag queue. Rather than adding a comment like this, I'd take the text you suggest and put that right into the flag by using a custom flag. That way, the context is presented at the point when we can use it.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume for a moment that the flag was handled by a moderator they don't have a lot of context when handling your flag.

The question was about handling text-input, transforming it and write the output. The answer says:

> > Also you need to check for the empty lines. May be that's a case in some situations. Your sample did not have it but if there is a chance ensure that you check for that as well.

That might apply, someone reaching that question while dealing with empty lines as well. You'll need to stretch the definition of Not An Answer to the limit, maybe beyond breaking point, but I can see a mod decline that flag for that reason.

It is by far a clear case of a valid decline by my standards. The difference is that I'm not a moderator...

In cases were you expect a moderator might err on the wrong side you better use a custom flag and explain what you expect the moderator to do. Converting to a comment would have been a possibility. The content it self is not without value in the context of the question. As an answer it is of low quality, not worth an up vote.

Comment: I take your point about what context the mods have, but that should be reflected in the NAA text to help reviewers. If the flag is only supposed to be used when "this does not look like an answer to any question that could remotely be asked by anyone on the planet," it should say that. It's frustrating when you do what the system says and get burned for it.