# Are answers such as "Clean and Rebuild" NAA?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, not-an-answer

I recently ran into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10405046) in the First Posts review queue:

> Please clean your application and build it again.

To me, this should be a comment, not an answer, as it is not a concrete answer to the question and more of a suggestion, possibly even asking for clarification from the author.  If cleaning and rebuilding did in fact answer the question, the question should be closed as a typo/no repro.

Naturally, I flagged the answer as NAA and moved through the queue.  Then I remembered this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276197/2415822) how we should not flag "answers which *look* like answers but *actually* do not answer the question."

Ultimately, the flag was declined.  Should "clean and rebuild" answers be considered answers?

Comment: Could "clean and rebuild" actually be the solution to the problem? If so, why wouldn't it be an answer?

Comment: In this case it easily *could* be an answer, since the error seems to be build-environment related.

Comment: sure why not. Maybe jazz it up with a little more rhetoric. Otherwise it may face a barrage of woe.

Comment: @BradLarson if cleaning and rebuilding solved the problem, why shouldn't the question be closed?  The no repro close reason clearly states: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was **resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.**"  I don't see how a cleaning and rebuilding answer helps other users.

Comment: That is most definitely a possible attempt to answer a question, so the NaA flag is not applicable.

Comment: @JAL if that error was resolved by a clean/rebuild then it isn't unlikely that other folks will have the same issue needing the same solution

Comment: @JAL - I've seen cases where "clean and rebuild" or something similar solved the problem for multiple users (as indicated by votes): http://stackoverflow.com/a/11010603/19679

Comment: in iOS develepment, sometimes this is the solution to those cryptic error messages Xcode throws at us developers. Cause you know, [Xcode sucks...](http://www.google.com/search?q=xcode+sucks)

Comment: Here's a similarly terse post in another field where a partially-speculative answer is good enough (according to the votes) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735461/httplistener-not-working-over-network/9735508#9735508

Comment: 'Clean and rebuild' is *frequently* **the** solution, especially in distributed applications, and therefore a valid answer.

Comment: ....or with any number of C++ build systems, especially when wrinkles such as Qt are involved.....

Comment: It might be an answer; it probably isn't a good answer. So NAA doesn't apply, but downvoting might.

Comment: just because an answer is trivial or not what you want to hear does not make it *not an answer*, it might make it a **wrong** answer but it is still and answer. If it is wrong downvote it, if it is incomplete downvote.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> To me, this should be a comment, not an answer

In most people's eyes, this probably should be a comment for obvious reasons

> as it is not a concrete answer to the question and more of a suggestion

Sometimes a good suggestion *is* the answer

> If cleaning and rebuilding did in fact answer the question, the question should be closed as a typo/no repro.

Not true. Being around Android for a little while now, I know that this *is* the answer to different issues when building an Android application

> Should "clean and rebuild" answers be considered answers?

Yes. It's not always the right answer or even a good one. But, sometimes it is both which makes it always *an answer* (in relevant circumstances, obviously. It's not an answer to "Why is my dinosaur now purple?"). Now, there may be times where this isn't a *good* answer which means it deserves a downvote and/or comment (maybe asking for more explanation).

Comment: As for why your dinosaur is purple, That's because *He loves you, you love him, you're a happy family. With a great...* Yeah you get the point :)

Comment: Note that even if the answer isn't relevant to the question, the NAA flag is likely to be declined, since moderators typically don't look at the question when reviewing NAA flags. (I have learned this the hard-ish way.)

Comment: It could be an answer to your dinosaur question if your dinosaur is made of Lego and you dropped it in purple paint.

Comment: I have a little confusion here. In Android, is this something you do *once* and the problem goes away forever, or is it something you have to do every build once it crops up?

Comment: @jpmc26 this is something that can be needed multiple times. It doesn't seem to be as much of an issue with Android Studio as it was with Eclipse but it still is needed from time to time.

Answer (score 9):

I know why it would flare more than one alarm: disjunction between the problem and the solution. When you read a question "My K doesn't work, why?" and someone answers "rebuild your keyboard" (and sometimes a "thanks, that works"), you wonder *"just what the hell is going on here?!"*.

You can't follow the logic on why would rebuilding the keyboard actually help OP key problem and certainly ignore less drastic solutions, yet they seems to "solve" the problem. And certainly, there are cases where removing the stub files helps (Latex comes to mind), but it would be nice that those answers explain why does it helps, in case that's a indicator for a bigger problem (Latex comes again).

Comment: This gets to the heart of what makes a GOOD answer over just an answer.  Good answers help to understand the logical context so that practitioners might have a better understanding of the system, rather than just a checklist of stuff to try when the project isn't working as expected.

Comment: In an ideal world this what we should be achieving to do. [but the](http://www.textfromxcode.com/post/128789275019/i-think-xcode-is-just-straight-out-trolling-me) [real world](http://www.textfromxcode.com/post/76999890289/glad-that-you-could-help-me-too-xcode) [is not](http://www.textfromxcode.com/post/42364971727/i-found-the-secret-to-making-provisioning-work) [so ideal...](http://www.textfromxcode.com/post/40188532757/xcode-koan-what-is-the-compiler-warning-for-not)

Comment: @Keale I feel a deep sadness for all developers using xcode, and present you all [some salvation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)