# Can links be flagged as "not relevant to this post", or does it need a custom flag?

Tags: support, comment-flags

When a comment is a link that is ***irrelevant*** to the post, how to get it removed?

I feel I should flag it "*It's no longer needed.*":

> [image]

But:

1. The comment has never been *needed* to begin with, because it has always been linking to something irrelevant.
2. When a moderator will review such flag, what will be their action?

   - auto-reject it: because mods aren't here to evaluate the relevance of a link without an explicit reason?
   - auto-accept it: blindly trusting me that the link is irrelevant?
   - will follow the link and do their evaluation if it's relevant or not?

Or, for links, should I always prefer the "*Something else.*" flag reason and always provide a written demonstration that the link is irrelevant?

Comment: The case where *"The comment has never been needed to begin with"* is definitely intended to be covered by the "no longer needed" flag. I don't like the flag name, in part because it makes it sound like the flag just means "obsolete", but really it's meant to be a superset of the old "obsolete", "too chatty" and "not constructive" flag classes, the latter two of which consist entirely of comments that were never needed. So *that* consideration, at least, shouldn't deter you from using a stock NLN flag in this situation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Definitely flag as

> It's no longer needed.

Let's not get hung up in hair-splitting formal semantics.

Comment: Eh? How does providing more explanation in a flag result in "pushing more work onto mods"? Surely it does the opposite, by reducing the amount of analysis they have to do personally? It's one thing to argue that there's *no need* to help out the mods with a custom explanation in this scenario, but I don't see how you're figuring that it *adds* work for them.

Comment: @Mark Amery: Stab in the dark but Jean-François might be taking into consideration the way our UI sorts flag options into their own bins. All the custom flags get lumped together and we have to analyze each one separately, whereas "no longer needed" flags are generally self-explanatory and easy to burn through. Not that I see a problem with that either since it really doesn't make any difference in practice - just making a guess as to their thought process.

Comment: @BoltClock does a link (such as the one from my screenshot) qualifies for the "no longer needed" bucket? If you reply yes, I'll mark Jean-François answer as accepted, but if you reply that it's better fit for the slow bucket, then I'll wait for you or Mark Amery to post a new answer explaining that.

Comment: @Cœur: Either sounds fine to me, and that's coming from a mod who is usually picky about semantics in flag options. Not sure what the other mods think but I can't imagine they'd care particularly either. We generally treat "no longer needed" as meaning either exactly that, or "never needed to begin with" (and I could write entire paragraphs distilling all the possible meanings of the latter, but I don't feel like undertaking that hassle atm).

Comment: @BoltClock oh, then Braiam has the most accurate answer?

Comment: @Cœur: No, if you want the most accurate answer, it's "mods can generally be trusted not to robo-review flags and you can expect them to handle most flags reasonably, including declining flags that are obviously the wrong choice, which implies that it matters to some degree what flag to use but not to hair-splitting degrees" ... ... you see where I was going with my parenthetical.

Comment: @BoltClock "mods can generally be trusted not to robo-review flags" considering that you basically use an algorithm to decide on NAA flags instead of looking at context like Shog told you all to do, I would say that SO moderators can not be trusted to robo-review standard flags.

Comment: @MarkAmery I blindly assumed that custom flags took longer to deal with than standard flags (because custom "things" usually takes more effort to deal with than standard "things"). But from BoltClock's comments I understand that the difference is marginal in this case. So I just went back and deleted that sentence to stop diverting attention from the main point, which is: flagging as NLL is just fine.

Comment: @Braiam The fact that you disagree with the way the community has decided to use the NAA flag doesn't mean people are robo reviewing them.

Comment: Thank you all. Note that if I were [plagiarizing Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), I would write: "_Even if the link was originally pointing directly to the most awesomeest answer ever for exactly the question being asked, there's nothing in the comment itself to even hint at what direction we're being pointed in. Strip the link and you're left with `click here`_". So a NLN flag should be fine; I've accepted Jean-François Corbett answer.

Answer (score 5):

The following quote from Meta Stack Exchange explains the two categories of comments in need of deletion:

> The essential problem here is that there are really only two broad categories of problems that we care about when it comes to comments:
>
> 1. comments that are inherently off-putting (to post authors, to casual readers, whatever)
> 2. comments that just take up space without contributing any useful information
>
> ...
>
> <sup>- [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) on [**New “no longer needed” flag reason title is incorrect**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298511/288751)</sup>

Shog9♦ goes on to elaborate that the No Longer Needed flag was intended for the latter category. The name "No Longer Needed" was chosen in the hopes of preventing users from selecting this flag for the former category.

So if a comment is **obviously** just taking up spacing without contributing any useful information and it isn't inherently off-putting, you can flag it as No Longer Needed.

If it is not obvious (domain knowledge or additional information is required to evaluate the relevance of the comment), a custom flag should be used and you should specify *why* it is not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

This essentially boils down to, "Will someone that's not an expert in the subject matter at hand be able to tell that that comment is not needed without any additional information?"

In the case of the comment in the picture, someone just linking to their answer *on the same question*, probably fits that bill.  Other people can see other answers if they want to look at them, and the question author is notified.  Now if the comment said something like, "I explain in my answer [link to answer] why [some technical point in your answer] is a problem", that'd be different.  Or if it was linking to an answer on an entirely different question indicating that it's a related (but not duplicate) post.

If you feel like the comment isn't useful, *but that someone who's not an expert won't be able to tell*, or because there's some non-obvious reason that it's not relevant that requires additional context, then use a custom flag and add that additional context.

Whether the comment was once needed or not doesn't matter.  If it's not *currently* relevant, "no longer relevant" is a fine flag.

Answer (score -9):

It doesn't matter which flag to use.

Comments are second class citizens. If it's not relevant to the post, it can't be incorporated to the post in the form of an edit. It's usefulness expired the same moment it was posted, just get rid of it.

Comment: This doesn't address the question (at least as I interpret it); Cœur isn't asking *whether* to flag, but rather what kind of flag (NLN or custom) to use.

Comment: @MarkAmery "Can links be flagged as “not relevant to this post”, or does it need a custom flag?" "just get rid of it". It doesn't matter which flag to use, just that it gets removed.

Comment: So, *"it doesn't matter which flag to use"* would be an answer to the question (albeit not one I'd unreservedly agree with), but that's not what your answer currently says. I'll edit.

Comment: As it stands, I'm still going to leave this with my -1 on it because I don't understand how anything in the second paragraph (i.e. the original content of the answer) justifies the position that it doesn't matter which flag to use, or indeed is relevant to the choice of flag type at all.

Comment: @MarkAmery because like Jean, I took into account how the UI for moderators behave. They can either accept the flag, which removes the comment or reject it which doesn't remove it. I'm banking that moderators would delete these comments no matter which flag is raised.

Comment: @Braiam given that The Powers That Be have been trying to make the flags distinct enough that users _won't_ just select flags at random, I think that telling people to select flags at random is bad advice.

Comment: @TinyGiant yeah, about that... I would [say that The Powers That Be said no.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276162/add-a-low-quality-posts-button-to-delete-answer-because-it-doesnt-answer-the-qu/276184#comment114491_276184) BTW, did you forget that we had 5 flag types on the comments?

Comment: @Braiam that was in 2014 and doesnt seem to mean what you think it means. Not to mention the fact that we only currently have 3 predefined reasons, and two of them are different scales of rudeness (which such comments are not), leaving the NLN flag or custom as viable options. Again that makes this answer look like patently bad advice.